# Ocultar botoes e Habilitar Outro com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma pagina e nela exibo um modal com 2 botões, um de confirmação e outro de cancelamento, conforme do código Abaixo: 
Dentro desse modal tenho uma **DIV** `<div class="resp"></div>` Essa div eu recebo uma resposta de uma pagina em **PHP**, gostaria de ocultar os 2 BOTÕES que tenho dentro desse modal e após receber a resposta da pagina **php** mostrar um outro botão para fechar esse modal. 
Como Posso Fazer ISSO?

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="md-default" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-center">
               <div class="i-circle primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
               <h4>Confirma o envio?</h4>
               <div class="resp"></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat enviar" >Sim</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

**Código da chamada ajax**

```
<script>
     $('.formulario').submit(function() {
         var form_data = new FormData();
         form_data.append('fileUploadAudio', $('input.fileUploadAudio').prop('files')[0]);
         form_data.append('titulo', $('input.titulo').val());
         form_data.append('mensagem', $('textarea.mensagem').val());
         form_data.append('tipo_notificacao', $('input.tipo_notificacao').val());
         $.ajax({
             url: 'postar.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
             type: 'POST',
             data: form_data,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function(response) {
                 $('.resp').html(response);
             },
             error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 alert(xhr.responseText);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
  </script>
```

Pagina para teste:
[LINK](http://williamvillar.com.br/Push_Novo/msg_simple_text.php)

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria a seguinte alteração no seu HTML, deixaria a `div.resp` com `display:none`, e deixaria um `button[data-dismiss=modal]` dentro dela, junto com uma div.msg, quando o ajax der a resposta, você adiciona a resposta dentro dessa `div.msg` e da um `fadeIn` na `div.resp`, e um `fadeOut` na `div.modal-footer`, o HTML ficaria assim:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="md-default" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-center">
               <div class="i-circle primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
               <h4>Confirma o envio?</h4>
               <div class="resp" style:"display:none">
                  <div class="msg"></div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
               </div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat enviar" >Sim</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Porque dessa forma o evento no `button[data-dismiss=modal]` já estaria funcionando, devido a chamada do bootstrap ao carregar a página, se deixar para colocar esse botão só depois junto da mensagem, terá de adicionar o evento ao botão, o que teria um retrabalho.

Espero que isso possa ajudar.

Comment: Leonardo, obrigado pela ajuda acho que sua solução funcionaria sim, coloquei aqui mas como a div está none, ela não vai ficar habilitada correto? na chamada do ajax teria que mudar esse none. Editei minha pergunta e coloquei a pagina de exemplo.

Comment: Pode ser no retorno do ajax, que iria mudar esse none, pode usar o fadeIn, o show, ou slideDown o que se adeque melhor ao seu caso, se estiver usando JQuery